# Doing some math in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I really need some help with some simple math in PHP. I've never done this kind of thing before but find myself in need of it. Here is what I am trying to accomplish;

I have a MySQL table called 'eval' which contains test scores and comments for all the students in my class.

Every month I test and evaluate my students in 4 areas, each having max total of 10 points.

The table rows look like this;

```
ID   name      participation   speaking   listening   writing   reading   comment

1   John Smith   Excellent       7            7          7       7         Teacher Comment.

2   Jane Brown   Excellent       6            7          7       6         Teacher Comment.

3   Mike Jones   Very Good       6            7          7       6         Teacher Comment.
```

I then display this data on a page in a table.

What I want to do is create an additional column in the table on the page and use some PHP to add up the 4 values (speaking, listening, writing, reading) and display the result as a percentage grade in the extra column.

Here is the code for selecting the table in MySQL

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_rsEval = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['group'])) {
  $colname_rsEval = $_GET['group'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_sgnesldb, $sgnesldb);
$query_rsEval = sprintf("SELECT * FROM eval WHERE `group` = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsEval, "text"));
$rsEval = mysql_query($query_rsEval, $sgnesldb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsEval = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsEval);
$totalRows_rsEval = mysql_num_rows($rsEval);
?>
```

And here is the code for the layout on the page

```
<td width="12" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $row_rsEval['ID']; ?></td>
<td width="145" valign="top" class="darkbrownbold"><?php echo $row_rsEval['name']; ?></td>
<td width="72" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $row_rsEval['participation']; ?></td>
<td width="55" align="center" valign="top" class="darkbrownbold"><?php echo $row_rsEval['speaking']; ?></td>
<td width="53" align="center" valign="top" class="darkbrownbold"><?php echo $row_rsEval['listening']; ?></td>
<td width="42" align="center" valign="top" class="darkbrownbold"><?php echo $row_rsEval['writing']; ?></td>
<td width="44" align="center" valign="top" class="darkbrownbold"><?php echo $row_rsEval['reading']; ?></td>
<td width="25" align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="350" valign="top"><?php echo nl2br($row_rsEval['comment']); ?></td>
<td width="45" align="center" valign="top" class="darkbrownbold"><?php echo $row_rsEval['top5']; ?></td>
```

I need the percentage total to display in the column before 'Comments'

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please add your current PHP code to display this table ...

Comment: Please change the title! It's quite obvious that you need help

Answer (score 6):

Use this as your SQL query

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       participation,
       speaking,
       listening,
       writing,
       reading,
       (speaking + listening + writing + reading) / 40 * 100 AS percentagetotal,
       comment
  FROM eval
```

Comment: Oh yeh, obviously that's a better idea - don't modify the table, just do the calculation on the fly. +1. Although, the only disadvantage here is that over many repeated selects, the processing overhead goes up - but the increase is so minimal as to be pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

First add a column `total_percentage` You can do that directly in MySQL using the following the query:

```
UPDATE `eval` SET `percentage`=((`speaking`+ `listening` + `writing` + `reading`)/0.4)
```

Comment: No need to add an extra column to the datatable that has to be kept correct, just use the DB query to do the math

Comment: But the asker wanted to create an extra column!

Comment: He wants to create an extra column in his output page, not necessarily in the database itself (especially when it's more work to do so)

Comment: Mark Baker is correct... I only need the column on the output page... Not on the database table...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have stored the scores in different variables, you can do something like this:

```
$total = $speaking + $listening + $writing + $reading;
$maxTotal = 40;
$percentage = round($total*100.0/$maxTotal);
```

And then display the $percentage value for each student.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I could get your mean.
You have 4 item and each one can be at most 10. So your maximum value is 40.
Now you need to do something like this :

```
<?php
$max = 40;
$current = $speaking + $listening + $writing + $reading;
$percentage = (100 * $current) / 40;
echo(number_format($percentage,'2','.','')); // echo with 2 digits after the point.
?>
```

Your needed value is `$percentage`;

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you want to make this calculation when the rows are inserted)

```
function get_percentage_grade ($speaking, $listening, $writing, $reading, $possibleTotal = 40) {
  return round((($speaking + $listening + $writing + $reading) / $possibleTotal) * 100);
}

$name = 'Dave Random';
$participation = 'Excellent';
$speaking = 7;
$listening = 7;
$writing = 7;
$reading = 7;
$comment = 'Teacher Comment.';
$percentage = get_percentage_grade($speaking,$listening,$writing,$reading);

$query = "
  INSERT INTO eval
    (name, participation, speaking, listening, writing, reading, percentage, comment)
  VALUES
    ('$name', '$participation', '$speaking', '$listening', '$writing', '$reading', '$percentage', '$comment')
";
```

The function `get_percentage_grade()` is the bit you want. This takes 5 arguments - speaking, listening, writing, reading (as numbers, int or float) and an optional "possible total" argument, that represents the maximun possible score. This, as you can see, defaults to 40 - you can alter this default simply by altering the function definition. It returns the percentage score, rounded to the nearest integer.

And don't forget to [escape your values](http://www.bobby-tables.com/) in your query :-)